# My fit looks shifted in respect to the observed time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, lags

I am using an ARIMA to find the fit and forecast a time series. The fit looks good despite the shift when i overlay the observed series and my fit model. Please see pic below:
[image: fit+observed+forecast]

What is possibly causing this shift?

Comment: [Searching for "shifted fit" in the ARIMA tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barima%5D+shifted+fit) (or similar) yields a number of previous threads on this. [This one may also be helpful.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/519413/1352) Try writing down your fitted ARIMA model in a similar way as in the answer to that post, that will usually be enlightening.