# Delayed fitted values and residuals for AR(1) model

Tags: r, time-series, residuals, autoregressive

I've fitted an AR(1) model using the below code.

```
library(forecast)
library(plotly)

Series <- c(6.89773674625742, 0.000530132677610595, 3.60550131815607, 2.61260697924526, 
-5.67819713941861, -4.86695619720548, -4.25371622897671, -2.83852411599092, 
-1.02142755625884, 0.0975249656270929, 2.41828420915933, 0.240800209049771, 
-0.734977693195882, -1.50910081729473, -3.08162111182198, -2.1525911214956, 
-0.322063954142248, -1.69009324737094, -0.556733134989541, 2.27796178680675, 
3.41393649344629, 3.85113556615436, 1.88950322626473, 0.628983369630767, 
3.36951960111171, 0.311055269097174, 0.253533500040614, 0.196897232972978, 
-2.05891074604055, -1.11394776952459, -0.668271254335238, 1.17806133245249, 
-3.57500749251673, -3.72753519514906, -2.97957919040639, 8.96880319092339, 
7.8175547351596, 5.96661837834184, 4.41593723848855, 5.06545464747813, 
0.715114182523543, 2.16485969721259, -2.28536464790999, -3.13561435524609, 
-8.08594456055685, -8.33641000391159, -2.78706500119167, -5.53796341617769, 
-8.6891586332399, -3.74070353065086, 3.4073495454525, -0.745051193554859, 
1.90204304590282, -3.15141833641214, 3.89451468871666, -2.56020719751388, 
-4.01563264014949, -3.47180958947231, -2.72878528077686, -1.68660621493897, 
0.154681860204195)

Dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2009-09-01"), as.Date("2009-10-31"), "day")

df <- data.frame(Series = Series, Dates = Dates)
arima <- auto.arima(y = df$Series, max.q = 0, max.p = 1, d = 0)

p1 <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Dates, y = ~Series, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", color = I("#2ca02c"), name = "Time Series") %>%
  add_trace(y = arima$fitted, name = "Fitted ARMA", color = I("#ff7f0e"))

p2 <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Dates, y = arima$residuals, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", color = I("#1f77b4"), name = "Residuals") %>%
  layout(title = "Residuals")

subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2, shareX = T) %>%
  layout(title = "ARMA fitting and residuals")
```

However, when looking at fitted values and residuals, fitted values are delayed by one day. And this causes an issue on the calculation of residuals : if we take a look at the green peak on 2009-10-06, the residual equals ~11, whereas I was expecting something around 3, as the "true" residual is the difference between the green peak on 2009-10-06 and the orange peak on 2009-10-07.

[image]

There's maybe something I'm missing on AR models, but how can I achieve the following ?

- Fitted values being "aligned" with original data
- Residuals being computed accordingly

Comment: Note to close-voters: this is *not* "programming or data request". This is a question about how ARIMA models work, specifically AR(1).

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the output of `dput(df$Series)`?

Comment: Also, take a look at the links in my comment at this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/573559/1352

Comment: @StephanKolassa, done, I've uploaded a subset of my data, which includes the dates disclosed on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the series is indeed AR(1), nothing in the data before 2009-10-06 could predict that there would be a peak of this magnitude at that day. So the prediction for this day, assuming that only what had happened before is known, will be much lower, and in fact it is. Only if you predict the next day, you can use the observation on the day before, and if there was a big jump to a peak, you will predict to bring up a high value again on the next day, and this looks like a "peak" in the predictions because this hadn't been expected one day earlier (although in fact you don't predict a peak here, you predict something slightly smaller than the peak on the day before, which can now be used for prediction but couldn't before).

Generally, when doing predictions based on an AR(1) model, what happened on the time point before is the major determinator for what is predicted on the next time point; the model assumes that at the next time point you'll see $\phi_1 X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, $X_{t-1}$ being the observation on the previous day, and its predictor, knowing earlier observations and having estimated $\phi_1$ by $\hat\phi_1$, is $\hat\phi_1X_{t-1}$. In this way you will predict that on the next day you see the observation from the day before, but a bit "regressed to the overall mean". This explains why the predictions in tendency look like the observations from *the day before*.

So in fact what you see there is correct, the predictions will look better aligned with the observation before than with the actual observation you're predicting. What you call "true residual" is in fact not a useful or "true" residual, because it would assume that to predict an observation on a certain day, you'd already know what this observation is, but this is of course not what prediction is about. So stick to what you computed and plotted; this looks alright. No further alignment needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. To give a bit more context, I am working on temperature data. The raw series given in the code is the de-trended and de-seasoned series. My concern is that since residuals of the AR(1) model are computed with the "shifted" fitted curve, I am not able to reproduce the behavior of the de-seasoned and de-trended series, especially extremes.

Would it be false to consider the residuals of the AR(1) model distributed according to the difference between the green curve and the orange non-shifted curve ?

Comment: @Vincent Reproduction is not prediction. I'm not sure what "reproducing the extremes" exactly means and what you need this for, but computing predictions from an AR(1) will for sure not "reproduce extremes" in the same place. Regarding your questions, I'm not sure what "consider... distributed according to..." means either (the difference between the curves is not a distribution; the residuals are these differences, that's just their definition).